# finfo_file(): Empty filename or path in CodeIgniter 4.0.4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having this error when I try to upload 1 image in CodeIgniter 4.0.4.

This is the error:
[finfo_file(): Empty filename or path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp1jT.png)

SYSTEMPATH/Files/File.php at line 153

```
152         $finfo    = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
153         $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $this->getRealPath());
154         finfo_close($finfo);
155         return $mimeType;
```

This is my code:

```
if ($img = $this->request->getFile('foto')) {
  if ($img->isValid() && !$img->hasMoved()) {
    $img->move('img/uploads/user');
    $namaFoto = $img->getName();
  }
} else {
  $namaFoto = 'user.png';
}
```

But when I try to upload multiple images, it works fine. This is the code to upload multiple images:

```
$fileFoto = $this->request->getFileMultiple('foto');

foreach ($fileFoto as $foto) {
    if ($foto->isValid() && !$foto->hasMoved()) {
      $foto->move('img/uploads/barang');
      $this->fotoModel->save([
        'slug' => $slug,
        'foto' => $foto->getName()
      ]);
    }
}
```

Is there a problem when CodeIgniter upgrade to version 4.0.4 because I did not experience problems when uploading a single file in version 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem too. maybe check your validation rules

```
'logo' => [
                'label' => 'Logo',
                'rules' => 'ext_in[logo, jpg,png]|max_size[logo, 200]'
          ]
```

before i just use *mime_in* rules. it always got error then i change to ext_in and its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I already got this.

Before I solved, my code is :

---move image to my directory----

and then

---validation for image---

So, the  solution is you have to validation first, and then you can move the image.

----validation image mime_in------

after you validate the image, you can move to director.

I hope this will be worked.